# Netbeans + xdebug with CLI PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, command-line-interface, xdebug

I was hoping someone could help with this:

I want to use xdebug to debug CLI PHP on a remote server. I'm not interested in debugging over the web.

I've set xdebug on the remote server, and port 9000 is open on my local machine. I know it connects since when I start debugging I can see it on the remote server's xdebug.log file:

```
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.123.195:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1"xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///path/scriptname.php"    language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="15612" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.3.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine>
<author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2015 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
```

I've two problems:

1) the scriptname.php file above isn't what I'm trying to debug. It's just one of many PHP scripts my remote server's cron runs periodically. I just want to debug what I'm working on at the time.

2) I can't actually debug the file which I do run. When I hit php myfile.php from the command line nothing happens, but on Netbeans I can't actually step into functions, see variable values or anything like that.

Am I missing something here? My php.ini values are as follows:

```
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.123.195
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
;xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

(when the last line is commented out I do export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=netbeans-xdebug" instead).

I don't even mind moving to a different IDE (I'm running Linux) as long as it works. But it has to be CLI execution on a remote server.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.